# Unique and random selection of 10 rows per user in a table

Tags: random, row

I have 1000 rows in an excel table related to 10 physicians. How can i randomly pick unique 10 rows for each of the 10 physicians

Currently I am using the pivot table to identify the total number of rows per physician. Then from the total row count per physician I am applying the mod(row(),n)=0, in conditional formatting by coloring the related cells, where n is the number of rows per physician / 10 (for example if a physician has 30 rows assigned to his name, that will be 30/10, which is 3). So it selects every 3rd, 6th row etc till it colors all the 10 cells. But when there are several users like over 50, it is time consuming. My excel version 2016.

Requesting your help